# IF Function leaving Date-Formatted Cell Blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, date-format, autofill

I have a cell Formatted as a date (M/dd/yyyy HH:mm).  The function in this cell is:

```
=IF($CX$30,MAIN_LEL_BUMP,"")
```

This is saying that if a check box is clicked (CX30), find the value of MAIN_LEL_BUMP, otherwise leave the cell blank.  The issue is sometimes the users do not enter the value of MAIN_LEL_BUMP and consequently the cell gets autofilled with 1/0/1900 0:00.  This will pass my date validation checker that I have, but needs to be the accurate date.  if MAIN_LEL_BUMP is not filled out, then it absolutely needs to leave the cell blank so that the data validation will pick it up as not being entered.  I have looked around on the web for this, and changing the "" to the actual cell name did not work either.  HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you need is one extra condition to check the value of that cell. The following formula will only use the value of MAIN_LEL_BUMP if your original criteria AND MAIN_LEL_BUMP is not empty. If either condition fails you will get your empty cell.

```
=If(AND($CX$30,MAIN_LEL_BUMP<>""),MAIN_LEL_BUMP,"")
```

Comment: I see what you are doing here.  This formula gives me the same result though: 1/0/1900 0:00.  Even though MAIN_LEL_BUMP is empty, I think it is performing the same function in that "" is the same as an empty MAIN_LEL_BUMP...which will populate the cell with a default date value. There has to be some sort of "leave empty" or "leave blank" function in excel, even if the cell is formatted as a DateTime...no?

Comment: Sorry I messed that up. I put MAIN_LEL_BUMP="". It should be not equals AKA MAIN_LEL_BUMP<>"". Answer Edited.

Comment: Just for future reference, why does the extra condition take the defaulted date out?  It seems like both formulas are saying close to the same thing... they both are returning a "" if MAIN_LEL_BUMP is empty. Not quite following the logic @Mark Balhoff

Comment: `MAIN_LEL_BUMP<>""` is in practice identical to `MAIN_LEL_BUMP<>0`. The latter is probably easier to use in an explanation. Dates are stored behind the scenes as a decimal number representing the number of days since 1/0/1900. Take a date cell with a date in it and change the data type to number and you will see what I mean. On the backend 1/0/1900 0:00 would be stored as 0 and say 1/15/2013 12:00 would be stored as 41289.5. So 1/0/1900 0:00 is not just a default value but actually the value of a zeroed out cell. The default value of that cell is 0 or "". Is that clear??

Comment: Ah, knew that about the dates and days, but did not about "" being day 0.  So my initial formula was telling it to return "", or 0, which would return 1/0/1900 0:00, whereas yours is telling it to make sure that MAIN_LEL_BUMP does not equal 1/0/1900 0:00 before it returns that value.  Thus the only way 1/0/1900 0:00 would return was if it was the value in MAIN_LEL_BUMP.  Makes sense.  THANKS MARK, very helpful.